# Android Badge Number not updating correctly android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am getting problem updating the badge number home icon of app as i will explain the scenario
Suppose User A send message to User B with notification id A1 and i setNumber(count) Suppose count is value stored on Shared preference then notification badge comes to 1 in this condition after notification increase count to 2 and in Shared preference also.Then Suppose User C send message to User B with notification id C1 then the value get 2+2(doubled) on badge then notification badge comes 4 automatically which needs to 3 and the process goes like this

Code for setting  Badge Number Count

```
      NotificationCompat.Builder summaryBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
            .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{0,500,1000})
           .setGroupSummary(true)
            .setNumber(count)
            .setGroup(jid);
```

I have also used

```
       ShortcutBadger.applyNotification(context,notification,AppPref.getUnreadCount()+1);
```

But same result comes on both case.Can you tell me how to reset badge value to zero.

Please don't suggest to use these as it not working on my mi phone

```
      try {
        ShortcutBadger.applyCountOrThrow(mContext,0);
    } catch (ShortcutBadgeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //always throws unable to execute badge
        
    }
    try {
        boolean success = ShortcutBadger.removeCount(mContext);
       

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //always throws unable to execute badge

    }
```